# Successive differentiation (implicit differentiation, second derivative)

Tags: calculus

Question :If $x^{1/2}$+$y^{1/2}$ = $a^{1/2}$ , find the value of $y''$ for x=a.

---

I differentiated once then twice and i got following equation

- $\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}+\frac{1}{2}y^{-1/2}y''=0$
- $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{2})x^{-3/2}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-1}{2}y^{-3/2}(y')^2+\frac{1}{2}y^{-1/2}y''=0$

If i keep $y''$ aside and transfer other terms on $R.H.S$

I get $y''=y^{1/2}(\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}+\frac{1}{2}y^{-3/2}y'^2)$

Now it is clear if i put value of $y^{1/2}$ ($from$ $relation$ $x^{1/2}+y^{1/2}=a^{1/2}$) On $R.H.S$ and put x=a whole $R.H.S$ becomes zero

But answer isn't zero in answer key on putting $x=a$ in r.h.s of $y''$

Comment: What does "bsc 29" mean?

Comment: I assume you are differentiating with respect to $x$. Then the derivative of $y^{1/2}$ is $(1/2)y^{-1/2}y'$.

Comment: BSc 29 nothing bSc is my course name and 29 is my question number

Comment: I also did differentiaition same way

Comment: Forgot to write that here sorry

Comment: Edited :)......

Comment: Please don't include strings like "bsc 29" in the title (or anywhere else really) – they're meaningless to everybody else. Instead, try to describe what the question is about mathematically. See the guide on how to choose [a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144).

Answer (score 1):

I think that we would get something different if we start with $y'$ using implicit differentiation.

Consider the function
$$f=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{a}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{y}}$$
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} } {\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} }=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}}$$ So, now, since $y$ is a function of $x$, then
$$y''=\frac{dy'}{dx}=\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2 x^{3/2}}-\frac{y'}{2 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}}=\frac{\sqrt{y}}{2 x^{3/2}}+\frac{1}{2 x}$$ and, if $x=a$, $y=0$. Then ...

Comment: Okay..this way i'm getting the answer...but is there anyway to know that such question should be solved with implicit differentiation that too starting with $y'$

Comment: @Akash. There are many ways to do it. Personally, I think the implicit functions and the implicit function theorem use to make things quite easy. Notice that, as done her, we could get $y'''$, $y''''$ and so on quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate by making proper arrangements [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZBIU.jpg)

Comment: Please, write it out here, don't just link to somewhere else.

Comment: @GerryMyerson What is the problem in seeing the picture

Comment: In general it's annoying having to click on some link to an external site in order to see the meat of the answer. It's harder to edit if there's an error somewhere, too. In this case, there's also the fact that the image is sideways, and that it doesn't zoom nicely in my browser.

Comment: @epimorphic sorry for inconvenience but I do not know how to type mathematical notation

Comment: See the help article ["How can I format mathematics here?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and the links there. If you want to get started with a graphical editor, see http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php

Answer (score 0):

Note that:
$$\begin{align}y"&=y^{1/2}(\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}+\frac{1}{2}y^{-3/2}y'^2)=\\
&=\frac12x^{-3/2}y^{1/2}+\frac{y'^2}{2y}=\\
&=\frac12x^{-3/2}y^{1/2}+\frac{\left(\frac{-x^{-1/2}}{y^{-1/2}}\right)^2}{2y}=\\
&=\frac12x^{-3/2}y^{1/2}+\frac{x^{-1}}{2}.\end{align}$$
Now you can evaluate $y''(a)$:

> $y''(a)=\frac1{2a}$.

Comment: $y''=y^{1/2}(\frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}+\frac{1}{2}y^{-3/2}y'^2$ But if i put value of $x$ without expanding the bracket..then i would get 0 and in the exam i don't know what is the answer is

Comment: We don't know the answer in the exam time and if i put x=a without expanding the bracket i would get r.h.s 0

Comment: note that you can not plug $x=a$ directly and use $y(a)=0$, because inside brackets you have $y^{-3/2}$, which is undefined. In fact, since the derivative is the limit, you get the indeterminate form $0\cdot \infty$. So, you must simplify before you plug $x=a$.

Comment: May i know, Why $y^{-3/2}$ inside the bracketes is undefined

Comment: "In fact, since the derivative is the limit, you get the indeterminate form" I didn't get it